# Cannot perform HTTP GET inside container from python script

Tags: python, docker, python-requests

I have a simple container running a python script which needs to perform a HTTP GET. Problem is, ping works fine, both resolving the name with mDNS as well as with standard IP.

However, the HTTP GET does not work and the script hangs on it. Clearly the same script outside the container works just fine. This is the errors I am getting:

```
>>> requests.get("http://iot-ns-controller.local:8081")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 174, in _new_conn
    conn = connection.create_connection(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 95, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 85, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 703, in urlopen
    httplib_response = self._make_request(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 398, in _make_request
    conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 239, in request
    super(HTTPConnection, self).request(method, url, body=body, headers=headers)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/http/client.py", line 1282, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/http/client.py", line 1328, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/http/client.py", line 1277, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/http/client.py", line 1037, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/http/client.py", line 975, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 205, in connect
    conn = self._new_conn()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 186, in _new_conn
    raise NewConnectionError(
urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7faa6658a0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 489, in send
    resp = conn.urlopen(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 787, in urlopen
    retries = retries.increment(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 592, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='iot-ns-controller.local', port=8081): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7faa6658a0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 73, in get
    return request("get", url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 59, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 587, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 701, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 565, in send
    raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='iot-ns-controller.local', port=8081): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7faa6658a0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused'))
```

It also does not work if I query `host.docker.internal` and I get the same error

Comment: Is `http://iot-ns-controller.local` run via Flask on your local network or? Could you elaborate on the flow and maybe share some simple code snippets of how it's setup?

Comment: http://iot-ns-controller.local is the hostname of my host machine, on which I have several services up and running. These services can be accessed with no problems outside of the container. I am simply trying to perform the HTTP GET which is not working, while (inside the container) ping works just fine.

Comment: Did you start the docker using sudo?

Comment: I would try to narrow down the problem. It's likely to be a docker configuration issue rather than a python issue. If it was a development setup, I'd probably extend the image to include something to help isolate the problem, like curl for instance, then connect to the image with something like `docker exec -it image_name bash`.

Comment: @user56700: no, I have the user in the docker group.

Comment: @JohnM.: curl works just fine inside the container

Comment: Connection refused implies the ip/port you're trying to connect to isn't listening. You could check to see what python is trying to connect to by running: `import socket; socket.getaddrinfo('iot-ns-controller.local', 80, proto=socket.IPPROTO_TCP)`

Comment: It is listening, because when I run the same script outside of the container it works

Comment: I wanted to confirm what IP address python is trying connecting to. I am assuming it's not the one you think it should be, particularly if curl is successfully connecting to the resource from the same container. I seem to remember having an issue with .local names before, but I can't remember the context.

Comment: @lbedogni Did you figure this out? I am having similar issue. curl works fine but running python script gives that error (which runs fine outside the container)

Comment: I worked around it. I basically avoided the mDNS resolution and now it works fine.